# Mule RSS FeedSplitter returns only one result if pubDate for all feed items is same

Tags: rss, mule

The rss:feed-splitter component of Mule returns only a single item even if the feed has more than one items if the pubDate for all the items is same.

Is there any way to get all the items in such a case?

Comment: Could you share a small sample RSS feed that allows reproducing the problem?

Comment: @david-dossot Feed would look something like this:
<rss version="2.0" ...>
    <channel ...>
        <description>Description</description>
  ....
        <item>
            <guid>localhost:8088/1</guid>
            <pubDate>2013-01-17T10:09:36.057+05:30</pubDate>
            <title>Title 1</title>
        </item>
  <item>
            <guid>localhost:8088/2</guid>
            <pubDate>2013-01-17T10:09:36.057+05:30</pubDate>
            <title>Title 2</title>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
Here both items have same <pubDate>, so FeedSplitter would return only 1 item instead of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that the `FeedSplitter` by default relies on the `EntryLastUpdatedFilter` to accept or reject feed entries. This filter is based on update time so any entry with the same time of another entry that has already been processed will be rejected.

I haven't found any clean way to configure the `<rss:feed-splitter>` element to accept all RSS entries so I had to instantiate it as a custom filter to be able to configure it, as shown below:

```
<custom-splitter class="org.mule.module.rss.routing.FeedSplitter">
    <spring:property name="entryFilter">
        <spring:bean class="org.mule.routing.filters.AcceptAllFilter" />
    </spring:property>
</custom-splitter>
```

This lets all RSS entries go through the splitting process.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [rss module documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/RSS+Module+Reference) the rss:feed-splitter

> Will split the entries of a feed into single entry objects. Each entry will be a separate message in Mule.

so what you are experiencing is the expected behavior.

What you can do is to code a custom aggregator that aggregates based on the pubDate so that the message propagated to the next message processor will be a mule message collection containing all the messages with the same pubDate

Comment: As the documentation says, I should receive each entry as a separate message, and I do get that behavior if <pubDate> for the feed items are different, but if <pubDate> is same for all items, the splitter returns only one item as a Mule message.